# How to increase MaximumErrorCount in SQL Server 2008 Jobs or Packages?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-job, sql-server-package

I have several jobs and several packages. In SQL Server 2005 we used to use DTS Packages, but they are now defunct (I know that I can re-enable them, but that's not what I'm after). I receive the following error by running one of my packages:

> Message: SSIS Warning Code
>   DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The
>   Execution method succeeded, but the
>   number of errors raised (1) reached
>   the maximum allowed (1); resulting in
>   failure. This occurs when the number
>   of errors reaches the number specified
>   in MaximumErrorCount. Change the
>   MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

Obviously, this is a result of an earlier error. I cannot fix that error, so I want to increase the `MaximumErrorCount`. But even though there are numerous posts on the internet explaining that you should select Properties on the package (or the job?), the package doesn't have *Properties* anymore (I found them under *Integration Services* where they're listed under *DTS Packages* which is odd, considering a wizard created the package and DTS is not supported by 2008?), I've no clue how to look into the package, really. And the job does have *Properties*, but nowhere is there a setting *Maximum error count*.

Can someone be the eyes for me and see what I cannot see? Where do I increase the MaximumErrorCount as requested by the error message?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I have open a package in BIDS ("Business Intelligence Development Studio", the tool you use to design the packages), and do not select any item in it, I have a "Properties" pane in the bottom right containing - among others, the `MaximumErrorCount` property. If you do not see it, maybe it is minimized and you have to open it (have a look at tabs in the right).

If you cannot find it this way, try the menu: View/Properties Window.

Or try the F4 key.

Comment: PS: all your suggestions bring up the properties of what's currently selected in the main pane. But I can't even get it selected...

Comment: BIDS = "Business Intelligence Development Studio", the tool you use to design the packages.
And the trick is to NOT select anything to get to the package properties.

Comment: Two notes:  (1) if you already have the package open, and want ***package*** properties, you can go to the "Control Flow" tab, right-click in the empty space between tasks, and select Properties.  (2) With SQL Server 2012, BIDS was replaced with SSDT-BI.  Online, that is usually referred to as "SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence", but on your start menu's apps listing, you may see it as "SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio".  Also note that SSDT and SSDT-BI are separate products (LOL).  For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14163142/1259871

Comment: Another note:  there is a `MaximumErrorCount` property on individual tasks, within the Control Flow.  Right-click a task, and go to properties.  I seen situations where it's helpful to increase this (for example to 1000) both at the package level, and at the task level.  (You still probably want to _resolve_ the errors, but at least with this setting, you get to see data.  After resolving errors, you may want to lower the value, so you are sure to be notified of problems.)

Answer (score 5):

It is important to highlight that the Property (MaximumErrorCount) that needs to be changed must be set as more than 0 (which is the default) in the Package level and not in the specific control that is showing the error (I tried this and it does not work!)

Be sure that in the Properties Window, the Pull down menu is set to "Package", then look for the property MaximumErrorCount to change it.

Comment: That still did not redirect the row to the error table, it still stopped the job even though I had allowed more errors than rows to be written.