# SSIS - Source Error Output (No rows will be sent to error output(s)....)

Tags: database, ssis

I'm a newbie in SSIS... I'm exporting data from a DBSource and outputing any errors to a Flat File. Now, when I connect the red arrow to the Flat Destination I'm receiving a warning from the DB Source "No rows will be sent to error output(s). Configure error or truncation dispositions to redirect rows to the error output(s), or delete data flow transformations or destinations that are attached to the error output(s)."

Does anyone know what it means? How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default, SSIS will "Fail component" on an error or truncation issue.  You must tell SSIS that you do not want to fail the package, but you want to "Redirect Row" which will allow the flow to continue down the red arrow.

- Edit your Source
- Go to the Error Output tab
- Set the relevant columns you want to trigger an error row redirect to Redirect Output as below.

This should remove the warning message you are currently getting

[image: Configure Error Output in SSIS]

Answer (score 0):

I had chosen the redirected rows in the source and still the warning remained. The mapping was good. Refreshing the metadata did not make it work.

I then removed the error path and the error table and put the two back in the data flow task. Then the warning was not shown anymore. It still did not redirect erroneous rows to the error table, but that must be another problem, see my remark at [How to increase MaximumErrorCount in SQL Server 2008 Jobs or Packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585122/how-to-increase-maximumerrorcount-in-sql-server-2008-jobs-or-packages) that setting the MaximumErrorCount to a high number does not lead to any error output.