# Using SSIS BIDS with Visual Studio 2012 / 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, visual-studio-2013, bids, sql-server-data-tools

I want to use SSIS /BIDS project in Visual Studio 2012.

I have both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 installed along with Microsoft SQL 
Server 2012.

VS 2010 was installed first followed by MS SQL 2012 which got me BIDS integrated with VS 2010.

However I cannot seem to find any help on integrating BIDS with VS 2012.

I came across few question on SO related to this topic but all of them had integration with 2010 and not 2012.

I know that with MS SQL 2012 I get a SQL Server Data Tool. Does this mean that Visual Studio 2012 and BIDS cannot be integrated ?

**Solution 2012:**

I had to update the solution here since one of the answers I received partially solved the issue. The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15258988/314763) provided by did solve the issue @user2141936 but I kept on getting an BlockMixedArchitectureInstall error while updating an existing instance.

It worked without  with creating a new instance!!

**Side Note** :
Installing the update broken my publishing database project onto 2012 server. You need to download and install a DACFramework patch for it.

**Solution 2013:**

download and install http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Comment: Just select new installation (I know it doesn't feel right but this gets rid of the block mixed architecture)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Welcome to Microsoft Marketing Speak hell. With the 2012 release of SQL Server, the BIDS, Business Intelligence Designer Studio, plugin for Visual Studio was renamed to SSDT, SQL Server Data Tools. SSDT is available for 2010 and 2012. The problem is, there are two different products called SSDT.

There is SSDT which replaces the database designer thing which was called Data Dude in VS 2008 and in 2010 became database projects. That a free install and if you snag the web installer, that's what you get when you install SSDT. It puts the correct project templates and such into Visual Studio.

There's also the SSDT which is the "BIDS" replacement for developing SSIS, SSRS and SSAS stuff. As of March 2013, it is now available for the 2012 release of Visual Studio. The download is labeled SSDTBI_VS2012_X86.msi Perhaps that's a signal on how the product is going to be referred to in marketing materials. Download links are

- [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36843) (SSIS packages target SQL Server 2012)
- [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313) (SSIS packages target SQL Server 2014)

None the less, we have Business Intelligence projects available to us in Visual Studio 2012. And the people did rejoice and did feast upon the lambs and toads and tree-sloths and fruit-bats and orangutans and breakfast cereals

[image]

Comment: I think this just out released in December 2012 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015

Comment: @frictionlesspulley Test it for yourself. For me, it only installs the database project. There is nothing SSIS related in there. I'm open and in fact will happily be proven wrong on this matter ;)

Comment: I will do my best to remember this question and notify you when the twittersphere rejoices in the release of the SSIS portion. ;)

Comment: @billinkc might this be the one that wins the Free Download of the Year award?? See http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Comment: @billinkc I beat you to it. Here it is: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36843

Comment: Is it still specific to a single version of Sql Server?  It's bloody frustrating needing to have a different Visual Studio installed for every version of Sql Server you need to dev SSIS packages for  :(

Comment: @Nick Pretty much, VS 2005 for SQL Server 2005, VS 2008 for SQL Server 2008 & 2008 R2, VS 2010 *or* VS 2012 for SQL Server 2012. See, that's an improvement </sarcasm>

Comment: +1 just for turning your answer into a biblical feast.  Made my day, plus the  info was good too ;)

Comment: @akousmata Methinks, that is more of a Monty Python reference than a biblical one. But then they were making a biblical reference so maybe I am just splitting hairs over the proper number of pointer dereferences to a joke--a sure sign I should go outside into the sun and escape my cube.

Answer (score 16):

Today March 6, 2013, Microsoft released SQL Server Data Tools – Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012 (SSDT BI) templates. With SSDT BI for Visual Studio 2012 you can develop and deploy SQL Server Business intelligence projects. Projects created in Visual Studio 2010 can be opened in Visual Studio 2012 and the other way around without upgrading or downgrading – it just works.

The download/install is named to ensure you get the SSDT templates that contain the Business Intelligence projects. The setup for these tools is now available from the web and can be downloaded in multiple languages right here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Comment: I installed this on a new vm with vs 2012 sp1 already on and it appeared to install fine, but I don't see Business Intelligence templates when I do new Project. Are there added steps I'm not aware of? I did a windows update and reboot and still no luck.

Comment: I got a BlockMixedArchitectureInstall error with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and SQL 2012 intance already installed !!

Comment: I already have SQL Server 2012 (x64) and VS2012 installed.  When running the installer I selected "existing instance" and got the BlockMixedArchitectureInstall error.  But, if I instead select "New Instance" it installs fine, and it doesn't actually create a new SQL Server instance on my machine.  A bit confusing but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

First Off, I object to this other question regarding **Visual Studio 2015** as a duplicate question.  `How do I open SSRS (.rptproj) and SSIS (.dtproj) files in Visual Studio 2015? [duplicate]`

Basically this question has the title ...`Visual Studio 2012 / 2013`  **What about ALL the improvements and changes to VS 2015 ???   SSDT has been updated and changed.**  The entire way of doing various additions and updates is different.

So having vented / rant -   I did open a VS 2015 update 2 instance and proceeded to open an existing solution that include a `.rptproj` project.  Now this computer does not yet have sql server installed on it yet.

Solution for ME  :   Tools --> Extension and Updates -->  Updates -->  `sql server tooling updates`

Click on Update button and wait a long time and SSDT then installs and close visual studio 2015 and re-open and it works for me.

In case it is NOT found in VS 2015 for some reason    :    scroll to the bottom,  pick your language iso    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396