# Can't resolve references to Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap in BIDS 2008 Script Editor

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bids

I am using the SSIS Script Component editor interface and I am unable to get the references to work.

- Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap
- Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap
- Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost

[image: SSIS project view in BIDS 2008 Script Component editor]

The DLLs exist and I can navigate to them here-- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies

I've tried deleting and re-adding the references (through the .NET tab and by browsing directly), but it hasn't helped. The error states "The referenced component... cannot be found."

[image: SSIS errors]

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working in BIDS 2008 but are trying to reference the DLLs for [SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162161.aspx). See [Using SSIS BIDS with Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162947/using-ssis-bids-with-visual-studio-2012) for ways to work with SSIS for SQL Server 2012, if that's what you're trying to do.

In BIDS 2008, you want the [SQL Server 2008R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162161%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) DLLs, located by default in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\**100**\SDK\Assemblies. (Note that the VSTA project **should** have those references set automatically when you edit the script for the first time.)

Comment: Thanks, this helped.  I had to rerun the SQL Server 2008 R2 installer, which restored the DLLs in the correct location.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem today whilst maintaining legacy work in BIDS 2008.

The DLLs were in the GAC on my install, so my case might have been slightly different.

BIDS 2008 refused to acknowledge them, I think because I had Sql Server 2012 installed on my machine.

As it was small job I renamed the dlls for sql server 2012 and then renamed them once I'd finished the work

So I temporarily renamed the files in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies

Not a long term fix!