# Convert SSIS (Visual Studio 2013) to work on SSIS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-2012

Is there a way of converting a SSIS package created in Visual Studio 2013 to work on SSIS 2012?

The start of my package looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
  DTS:refId="Package"
  DTS:CreationDate="12/18/2014 8:53:33 AM"
  DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:CreatorComputerName="LOCAL111"
  DTS:CreatorName="username1"
  DTS:DTSID="{C6D60123-5529-4BC1-B426-B219A0709EB7}"
  DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="12.0.2430.0"
  DTS:LocaleID="1044"
  DTS:ObjectName="ZVENDGLO import"
  DTS:PackageType="5"
  DTS:VersionBuild="321"
  DTS:VersionGUID="{E6195A4D-907C-4597-8448-C4E56027883A}">
  <DTS:Property
    DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
  <DTS:ConnectionManagers>
...
```

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short and long answer, unfortunately, is no. If you want to develop SSIS/SSDT for SQL Server 2012, you must use the Visual Studio environment that came with 2012.

Here's the long version of the background info. To build SSDT packages for SQL Server 2012, you actually use Visual Studio 2010. VS2010 is the BIDS environment that came with SQL Server 2012. People very colloquially call it SSIS 2012, but that's a misnomer, and with the very weird backwards compatibility issues surrounding SSIS across these versions, it's important to get the terminology about development environments right. Additionally, you are developing packages in Visual Studio 2013, but that technically is only for SQL Server 2014.

The interesting thing is you can use VS2013 (the developer tools included with 2014) to build SSRS and SSAS solutions for SQL Server 2008 through present, but that flexibility does not extend to SSIS/SSDT. You must use SSDT for VS2010 if you want to deploy packages on SQL Server 2012, and you must use SSDT for VS2013 if you want to deploy packages for SQL Server 2014.

Sources:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2014/04/02/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-ssdt-bi.aspx

[Anyway to deploy a SSIS 2012 project built in VS 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126574/anyway-to-deploy-a-ssis-2012-project-built-in-vs-2013)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping that since this is a XML based file format, someone had written some kind of transformation thing to convert into a previous format.

Comment: Glad I could help. Sorry, I haven't found any such tool. You'd think that MS would allow backwards compatibility of some sort, seeing as how SSAS and SSRS have such great compatibility across versions, but no luck with that yet.