# Installing SSDT 2012 and VS2013 Pro on my workstation?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

Our server has Windows Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2 and VS2008 Pro installed. They're used to create Business Intelligence projects such as SSRS reports and SSIS packages. We already have SSRS and SSIS deployed, and we're already using ReportServer to view the reports. Unfortunately, we need to connect to the server via Remote Desktop to create these packages and reports.

These tools were already installed when I got here and we don't have the CDs for any of them.

So I just received the MSDN CDs for SQL Server 2012 and VS2013 Professional. I want to install in my workstation so that I can work locally and then deploy/copy the project to our server.

From my understanding, I need both SQL Server 2012 and VS2013 Pro to create SSDT packages, but I'll be deploying to the server.

Is this something that's possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Youк server is SQL/SSIS 2008, your development workstation will be VS2013. Your packages created in VS2013 will **be incompatible** with SSIS 2008. Only VS2008 from Visual Studio or BIDS from SQL 2008 distributive will generate compatible packages.
For distributive - you can download SQL2008 distributive from MSDN site and install only BIDS - Business Intelligence Development Studio - which does not require any license.

Comment: If I upgrade from SQL2008 to SQL2012 in the server and I install VS2013 in my development workstation, can I develop SSDT BI projects and deploy in the server?

Comment: Although it seems to me from [this SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126574/anyway-to-deploy-a-ssis-2012-project-built-in-vs-2013) that deploying an SSDT BI project in VS2013 to Sql Server 2012 is not easy.

Comment: If you upgrade your SQL/SSIS instance to 2012, I'd likely just install the latest version of SSDT (using the VS2015 shell) because it can dev SSIS 2012, 2014, and 2016.

Comment: @rbhatup, with VS2013 you can develop packages only for SSIS 2014. I agree with Peter, with VS2015 and SSDT you can create packages for all SSIS versions after 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need VS2013 installed on your local machine; however, you don't necessarily need SQL Server installed.  If you want to develop your SSIS packages against databases on the server, you can simply set your data source and/or destination to the server name within your SSIS package.  You can run the SSIS package locally until it works properly, then save off the .dtsx package and then deploy on the server via Remote Desktop.

Having SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) installed locally will be a big help in your development as you can deploy from SSMS to the server, but you don't need SQL Server itself (i.e. the database engine and related services) installed locally in order to do that.

However, if you want your local machine to be a full test environment where you're testing the database as well as the SSIS package 100% locally and then deploying to the server, then yes, you'll need SQL Server engine installed locally.

Comment: So I can install `VS2013` in my workstation, create an `SSIS` or `SSRS` package with `VS2013` and deploy to the server with `SQL2008`?

Comment: You'll need the BIDS IDE for SQL 2008 to build/publish SSIS packages for SQL 2008.  I think that actually runs in the VS 2010 shell, but it's hard to say for sure. You'll have the proper bits installed if you install them from the SQL 2008 setup files.