# Can I develop reports in Visual Studio 2013 without having a local copy of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm migrating to a new computer, and I currently have the following installed on my old machine:

1. SQL Server 2012
2. Business Intelligence Tools for Visual Studio 2013
3. SQL Server Management Studio
4. SSRS 2012

I'm creating reports in Visual Studio 2013 but I use a remote SQL Server database.

My question is do I need to have SQL Server 2012 installed on my new machine to be able to create reports?

Comment: You have to install *at least* the SQL Server **Reporting Services** to be able to author and view reports anyway - and it would probably be a lot easier if you had some kind of database locally, too, to grab some data to show....... you might not *have to* install SQL Server (the engine/core) - but I would do it anyway

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but does this mean that I can install the Reporting Services without having SQL Server installed ?

Comment: I honestly don't know - I've never felt the need to try that ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) if its SQL Server 2008R2 and before (2005-2008R2) and SSDT for higher versions. Its very convenient to have SSMS but not necessary. For an excellent article on how to install (and where to find SSDT) please see:

[Using SSIS BIDS with Visual Studio 2012 / 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162947/using-ssis-bids-with-visual-studio-2012-2013)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to install Sql Server. You will want Management Studio installed on your new machine, but you can do that without installing the full database engine, and the program installed on your machine can connect to the database services running on your old machine.

You may need to change some security settings on your old operating system to allow connections through the firewall, on the database server to allow connections from outside the local machine and to create an account you can use to log in, and on the database within the server to give the new account access to the tables and other items you need.