# SSIS Balanced Data Distributor 2014 SP1 for VS 2012 doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to install SSIS Balanced Data Distributor 2014 SP1 for Visual Studio 2012, but this component is not displayed in the SSIS Toolbox.

I install x86 version of this component. The TxBDD.dll is located in the directory correctly: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents

Also I put the TxBDD.dll to the directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents

How can I fix it?

Comment: Also I put the TxBDD.dll to the directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents

Answer (score 2):

- SQL Server 2014 -> Visual Studio 2013
- SQL Server 2012 -> Visual Studio 2012

You have downloaded a component for the designer associated to VS 2013 and expect it to work in 2012. That's not a feature of the designer at this point.

The resolution is to get the 2013 [SQL Server Data Tools-BI edition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14163142/181965) installed. That will allow you to use the BDD component (and nothing else will)

Comment: Thank you for this infomation. We can't to change the version of SSDT right now. As temporary solution we decieded to use a "Conditional Split" component.