# SSDT Business Intelligence with Visual Studio 2013 install error "The .NET Framework 4.5.1 is required"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, bids

So, I am currently unable to install SSIS BIDS for Visual Studio 2013 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313).  I have Visual Studio 2013 and Sql Server 2014 Developer version.  I am getting an error right away that says "The .NET Framework 4.5.1 is required for SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence."  I have .NET 4.5.1, I can actively target that framework, and just to be sure I tried to install the 4..51 client profile again but it says I already have a newer version installed.

I have seen that in this question: [Using SSIS BIDS with Visual Studio 2012 / 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162947/using-ssis-bids-with-visual-studio-2012-2013), that some people were experiencing an architecture error, but that is not the error I am getting.  Really stuck on this, any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want SSDT, not BIDS. It was renamed a few years ago. The link for your version should be here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313 ; And I see that you linked that in your answer. Have you tried uninstalling .NET 4.5.1 and letting it install it from the SSDT setup?

Comment: Yeah no dice, still same error.  I'll update the title as well.